# How to write a system agnostic Python daemon/service?

Tags: python, service, daemon, os-agnostic

Since [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) is restricted to *nix systems, what is the easiest way to write a python program that can act as both *nix and Windows services in a Pythonic way?

Comment: if you have python installed on windows it should run... May have to set up your path correctly first.

Comment: @Hoopdady `pip install python-daemon` fails with "No module named resource". Anyway I'd prefer a service as in auto-restarting on failure

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.